# Traversable instance for general type composition

Tags: haskell, types, composition

I am completely stuck on this is an exercise from the excellent [Haskell Programming](http://haskellbook.com) book.

Given the following newtype for type composition and instances of Functor and Applicative, write an instance of `Traversable (Compose f g)`.

```
newtype Compose f g a =
  Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
  fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose $ (fmap . fmap) f fga

instance (Applicative f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Compose f g) where
  pure = Compose <$> pure . pure
  Compose f <*> Compose x =
    Compose $ ((<*>) <$> f) <*> x
```

My proposed solution looks like it should work, based on the type of `traverse.traverse` but ghci complains.  I have a vague feeling it is something to do with re-wrapping in the `Compose` constructor:

```
instance (Traversable f, Traversable g) => Traversable (Compose f g) where
  traverse f1 (Compose fga) = (traverse.traverse) f1 fga
```

gives the type error:

```
composing_types.hs:69:31:
    Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘g b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            traverse :: Applicative f1 =>
                        (a -> f1 b) -> Compose f g a -> f1 (Compose f g b)
          at composing_types.hs:69:3
    Expected type: f1 (Compose f g b)
      Actual type: f1 (Compose f g (g b))
    Relevant bindings include
      fga :: f (g a) (bound at composing_types.hs:69:24)
      f1 :: a -> f1 b (bound at composing_types.hs:69:12)
      traverse :: (a -> f1 b) -> Compose f g a -> f1 (Compose f g b)
        (bound at composing_types.hs:69:3)
    In the expression: (traverse . traverse) f1 fga
    In an equation for ‘traverse’:
        traverse f1 (Compose fga) = (traverse . traverse) f1 fga

composing_types.hs:69:54:
    Couldn't match type ‘f’ with ‘Compose f g’
      ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at composing_types.hs:68:10
    Expected type: Compose f g (g a)
      Actual type: f (g a)
    Relevant bindings include
      fga :: f (g a) (bound at composing_types.hs:69:24)
      traverse :: (a -> f1 b) -> Compose f g a -> f1 (Compose f g b)
        (bound at composing_types.hs:69:3)
    In the second argument of ‘traverse . traverse’, namely ‘fga’
    In the expression: (traverse . traverse) f1 fga
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### H O L E S

This is another great question that can be solved with holey expressions.

First, let's assume we have Foldable instances all defined already.

```
λ> instance (Foldable f, Foldable g) => Foldable (Compose f g) where
     foldr = undefined
```

Next, instance Traversable. Pattern match on the `Compose` argument because you know you will have to, but otherwise leave everything in a hole.

```
λ> instance (Traversable t, Traversable u) => Traversable (Compose t u) where
     traverse a2fb (Compose tua) = _ tua
```

GHC will helpfully spit out an error–

```
<interactive>:...:...
  Found hole ‘_’ with type: f (Compose t u b)
```

–in addition to the types of all variables in scope.

```
Relevant bindings include
  tua :: t (u a) (bound at ...)
  a2fb :: a -> f b (bound at ...)
  traverse :: (a -> f b) -> Compose t u a -> f (Compose t u b)
    (bound at ...)
```

(I have chosen the type and value names so that everything lines up neat. Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain.) Now then the question of the hour: how to conjure a value of `f (Compose t u b)` given everything else. We know

- The only way to construct `Compose t u b` is by creating a value `t (u b)`.
- There is no way to produce a value of `f anything` except by (1) `pure` and (2) `fmap`, and intuitively we know we cannot use `pure` because we are trying to collect the 'side effects' of `a2fb :: a -> f b` here.

This leads us to our next stab at the solution.

```
λ> instance (Traversable t, Traversable u) => Traversable (Compose t u) where
     traverse a2fb (Compose tua) =
       fmap Compose (_ tua)

<interactive>:...
  Found hole ‘_’ with type: t (u a) -> f (t (u b))
```

At last we have a `t`. We know `t` is Traversable so let's try traversing it.

```
λ> instance (Traversable t, Traversable u) => Traversable (Compose t u) where
     traverse a2fb (Compose tua) =
       fmap Compose ((\tua -> traverse _ tua) tua)

<interactive>:56:138:
  Found hole ‘_’ with type: u a -> f (u b)
```

Same deal. We know `u` is Traversable so let's try traversing it.

```
λ> instance (Traversable t, Traversable u) => Traversable (Compose t u) where
     traverse a2fb (Compose tua) =
       fmap Compose ((\tua -> traverse (\ua -> traverse _ ua) tua) tua)

<interactive>:57:155:
  Found hole ‘_’ with type: a -> f b
```

A goldilocks hole for our `a2fb`.

```
λ> instance (Traversable t, Traversable u) => Traversable (Compose t u) where
     traverse a2fb (Compose tua) =
       fmap Compose ((\tua -> traverse (\ua -> traverse a2fb ua) tua) tua)
```

Eta-reduce to excise the lambdas, and you end up with [the solution](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/src/Data-Functor-Compose.html).

```
λ> instance (Traversable t, Traversable u) => Traversable (Compose t u) where
     traverse a2fb (Compose tua) =
       fmap Compose (traverse (traverse a2fb) tua)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! or `fmap Compose $ (traverse . traverse) f1 fga`, which I find shows the double traversal more clearly.

Comment: Yes! Being able to write this as a composition of `traverse . traverse` is one of the inspirations for the design of the `lens` package.